# Why are Google Analytics cookies attached to my images?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, varnish

I'm working with my host to resolve a Varnish caching issues. Long story short they're telling me that due to a Google Analytics cookie set, the caching is failing.

So I remove all traces of GA code from my site. Viewing the source there is no GA code anywhere.

However, upon using the dev console to analyze headers, I'm seeing a lot of:

```
Cookie: _ga=1.2.286403989.1366364567;
```

...attached to my images. Can anyone provide any insight as to where is this coming from?

Here's a screenshot of the dev console output for just one particular image:

[image]

Comment: From GA cookies ? Just because you removed the code does not mean returning visitors do not already have a cookie set.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Haha, yes. If it isn't painfully obvious I'm not too well versed in web development. This is what they told me though, and they said they had removed the cause of the cookies being set.

I didn't realize I was simply observing my cookie which had *already* been set in the past. After clearing my cookies, it is gone. Though I do not know how this translates to my users needing to do the same in order to get their browser to accurately receive the cached website, the presence of the cookie is making it fail.

Comment: This are first party cookies (GA sets first party cookies because the js code is injected into the page), so in theory you would be able to unset the cookie via Javascript.

Comment: Tsk! :) Removing GA is not solution to GA breaking Varnish from cache. Configuring Varnish to strip GA's cookie is a proper solution.